# How to convert UTC plus time zone to date and time string

Tags: java, jodatime

I am sure there is a simple way to do this (with Java 1.7).  We have a messaging server that inserts dates like:

20160901084500+0800

The format is:

YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.UUUU[+|-ZZzz]

The output I am after is:

YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

adjusted for the timezone offset.  I have just started looking at Joda time, but I am not exactly sure how to ensure the timezone correction.

Comment: Your date doesn't match either format. What does `U` represent? In what way are you looking to "adjust" the time zone? Can you include sample output?

Comment: Based on you input, something like `YYYYMMddHHmmssZZ` should work for `SimpleDateFormat` (assuming I interrupted you input correctly), but I'd highly recommend spending the time to work with JodaTime

Comment: The date format is commonly used with HL7.  Pathology data is often sent with UTC+Timezone.  We would like to use the time stamp as an adjusted time (without the timezone).  I will need to check the UUUU

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to java 8 instead of 7? Look at `java.time.LocalDateTime`

It isn't clear from your question what you want to do with time zones, but the Java 8 time package can handle it.